# Input answer: value and number of occurence of largest number

Tags: c++, max

**Problem Statement**

Rarity loves diamonds!

In fact, right now, Rarity is collecting diamonds. It's no surprise that Rarity loves the rarest, shiniest diamonds, so she's always concerned with how shiny her diamonds are.

Rarity has Q queries about her diamonds, and she wants you to answer them, because she obviously doesn't want to answer them herself.

At first, Rarity has no diamonds. But, in the process of her diamond-hunting, the following may happen:

Rarity finds some diamond with a shininess S.
Rarity wonders how shiny the shiniest diamond is, and how many diamonds are the shiniest among all her diamonds. If there are no diamonds, you must output fail.
You decided to help Rarity in this task. For each query of the second type, answer her, how shiny the shiniest diamond is, and how many diamonds are the shiniest.

**Input Format**

The first line contains a single integer Q, the number of queries.

The next Q lines each start with a word, that determines the type of query:

If the line starts with ADD, a single integer S follows, the shininess of the diamond that was just found.
If the line starts with ASK, Rarity asks for the shininess of the shiniest diamond and the number of diamonds that are shiniest.
Output Format

For each ASK query, output two integers on a single line, the shininess of the largest diamond and the number of diamonds that have this shininess.

If there are no diamonds when she gives an ASK query, output instead fail on a single line.

**Constraints**

Subtask 1 (13 points) 
1≤Q≤106 
1≤S≤109

Subtask 2 (30 points) 
1≤Q≤1 million
1≤S≤109

Subtask 3 (27 points)
1≤Q≤106
1≤S≤1 billion

Subtask 4 (30 points)
1≤Q≤1 million
1≤S≤1 billion

**Imperfect Code**

Score: 70.00. Verdict: Time Limit Exceeded (TLE)

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        long long int numberofqueries, numberofqueriesdone, shininess;
        cin >> numberofqueries;

                long long int shiniestdiamond = 0, numberofsuchdiamonds = 0;
                string questiontype;

        while (numberofqueriesdone < numberofqueries)
            {cin >> questiontype;
                if (questiontype == "ASK")
                {
                    if (shiniestdiamond == 0)
                        cout << "fail" << endl;
                    else
                        {cout << shiniestdiamond << " " << numberofsuchdiamonds                 << endl;}

                }

                if (questiontype == "ADD")
                {
                    cin >> shininess;

                    if (shininess == shiniestdiamond)
                        numberofsuchdiamonds += 1;
                    else if(shininess > shiniestdiamond)
                        {shiniestdiamond = shininess;
                        numberofsuchdiamonds = 1;}




                }


                numberofqueriesdone += 1;
            }
    }
```

**What's wrong**

I can't see what wrong with my code that would give a TLE verdict. I'm confident that it will run in at most 10M calcs.

Comment: " If the line **starts** with ASK" sounds to me like they are explicitly expecting code to discard the remainder of the line before reading anything else, and to test only those first characters.  I don't see any such code in what you posted.

Comment: I think my solution works but I just don't understand why will it go over 2s with 1 mil instructions

Comment: If you parse input incorrectly, your program will then be waiting for input while the driving program either is waiting for your output, or has no more input to give.  The driving program then aborts your program for TLE.  So if you **think** your solution works, and are only wondering why it is too slow, you are not thinking with an open mind.

Comment: But it gives correct answer for all smaller cases

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior, you never initialize `numberofqueriesdone`.

Comment: It still gives TLE even after fixing it